# Symbol "aligned_alloc" missing when loading OpenAL Soft

Tags: android, android-ndk, c11, openal-soft

I've compiled OpenAL Soft with the NDK r17.1.4828580 using the following command:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android -DANDROID_NDK=$$ANDROID_NDK_HOME \
    -DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=armeabi-v7a -DALSOFT_BACKEND_OSS=OFF \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=clang \
    -DALSOFT_BACKEND_WAVE=OFF ..
```

[In OpenAL Soft's CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/kcat/openal-soft/blob/5cba81cf35ff7f8b6739b317ada82163899a3168/CMakeLists.txt#L507) there's a check for [aligned_alloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/aligned_alloc) which seems to be a new function in C11. The check and the build succeed, but when I'm trying to load the resulting libopenal.so with dlopen, I'm getting the following error message:

```
dlopen(libopenal.so): dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "aligned_alloc" referenced by "/data/app/com.bixense.jngl_test-2/lib/arm/libopenal.so"...
```

Is there some kind of C11 stdlib shared object file I need to load first?

Comment: It's possible that the check was performed against the wrong version of the library. I've seen feature detection systems check the static library but use the shared library before. In the case of the NDK, the static library is always as complete as possible, but the shared library will depend on your minSdkVersion.

Answer (score 0):

Passing `-DCMAKE_ANDROID_API=23` to CMake fixed it, since it will result in:

```
-- Looking for aligned_alloc - not found
```

I guess I would have been able to load the shared library on an Android phone with Oreo (API level 26) or newer.